# How - Convert Linq.DataQuery to Generic.List

Tags: c#, linq

Would anyone of you could help me solve this? I'm getting this error when casting 'carsList' variable to '_vehicleList'

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VehicleDAOModel]'.**

Does the Linq.DataQuery has to match the Properties in VehicleDAOModel?

My code:

```
public class VehicleDAOModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int _Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Year")]
    public string _year { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Make")]
    public string _make { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public string _model { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Trim")]
    public string _trim { get; set; }
}
        // LINQ TO SQL CODE

       var dataContext = new VehicleModelL2SQLDataContext();
        var carsList = from v in dataContext.Vehicles
                       select v;
        _vehicleList = (List<VehicleDAOModel>)carsList;

       public List<VehicleDAOModel> _vehicleList = new List<VehicleDAOModel>();
```

Tried the following but did NOT work:
carsList.ToList(); (X)
carsList.AsEnumerable().LoList(); (X)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the structure of Vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `.ToList()`on that `carsList`.

```
_vehicleList = carsList.ToList();
```

That carsList is a query that will be executed, once it's read from. The .ToList() reads the complete query result and returns it as a `List<T>`.

But that does expect the query to return `VehicleDAOModel`s. If not, then you will need to use .Select() and convert it yourself.

Comment: I think he should declare `vehicleList` before the `linq` statemenet.

Comment: He doesn't need to declare it before the query, just before he assigns a value to it. I understood that code as a sample of the real lines, not necessarily in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Tried the following but did NOT work: 
carsList.ToList(); 
carsList.AsEnumerable().LoList();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your vehicle entity class is not named "VehicleDAOModel" you need to *project* `carsList` to a list of `VehicleDAOModel` objects.

```
_vehicleList = carsList.Select( c =>
                   new VehicleDAOModel {
                       Id = c.Id,
                       Year = c.Year,
                       ...
                       });
```

I would strongly recommend to use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) for this:

```
Mapper.Map<Vehicle, VehicleDAOModel>();
_vehicleList = carsList.Project.To<VehicleDAOModel>();
```

(Assuming that there is a 1:1 mapping of property names between both classes.)